# Is there any proofs/rules/properties for this or similar situations, if so what does it call?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If the sum of $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ is a constant c, then the optimization/critical point of function $F(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, where $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ are interchangeable, is $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=c/n$

Comment: This is untrue, so no.

Comment: In the broadest case then it's probably untrue, but it seems to be true in many specific cases, so I wonder if there is some kind of properties with some restrictions in there. For example, it's true for $F=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$. I suspect it's true for $F=x_1^2+x_2^2+..+x_n^2$ and $F=x_1^{2k}+x_2^{2k}+..+x_n^{2k}$ as well. Hence I wonder what specific restrictions need to be put in place here.

Comment: It's true for convex criteria.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.